# Fubini term by term differentiation proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying real analysis and find something difficult to understand.
 
**THM**. Given monotone increasing function $f_{n}:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$, $(n=1, 2, \ldots)$, put 
$$
s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n f_{k}.
$$ 
If $s_{n}$ converges pointwise to $s$, then 
$$
s'=\sum_{n_=1}^\infty (f_{n})'.
$$

At first I want to understand why
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f_{n})'\le s'
$$
Please help or give me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming each $f_k$ is differentiable on $[a,b]?$ Why do you think $s$ is differentiable?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add some conditions. Cause $f_k$ is monotone increasing, so differentiable almost everywhere. Differentiation statement above means "almost everywhere"